# Can you use firebug lite to debug IE 8 without injecting code?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, firebug-lite

Is there anyway to download something for IE that allows me to debug IE 8? Is there a downloadable version of firebug lite that does not require placing code in the head of my file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Firebug is amazing, and Firebug Lite is handy, for debugging IE I highly recommend IE's [Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - just hit F12.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need Firebug specifically, you can use Internet Explorer's developer tools. To open them, press F12 or select Tools -> Developer tools from the program menu.

The IE developer tools are not as good as, let's say, Chrome's, but they might be able to do what you need.

I think you can find some more info about them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa740478).